# Linux route selection not taking expected rule

Tags: routing, vlan

I have the following routing rules (displayed using `route -n`):

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination  Gateway    Genmask         Flags Metric Ref Use Iface
0.0.0.0      10.0.2.1   0.0.0.0         UG    100    0     0 enp0s3
10.0.2.0     0.0.0.0    255.255.255.192 U     100    0     0 enp0s3.100
10.0.2.0     0.0.0.0    255.255.255.0   U     100    0     0 enp0s3
169.254.0.0  0.0.0.0    255.255.0.0     U     1000   0     0 enp0s3
```

The interface `enp0s3.100` is a interface with VLAN id 100.

If I try to get the route for 10.0.2.70, I expect it to use the VLAN interface, but it does not:

```
# ip route get 10.0.2.70
10.0.2.70 dev enp0s3  src 10.0.2.11 
    cache
```

Does anyone know why the longest prefix match is not being used here ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, it's best to only use the `ip` commands, so you should have used `ip route show` (or `ip r` for short) to list the routing table.

In this case, the route over the VPN is for 10.0.2.0/255.255.255.192 or 10.0.2.0/26. This subnet is 0 - 63. Your example destination 10.0.2.70 falls *outside* of this range, hence it's not routed over the VPN but instead uses the next-more-specific route of 10.0.2.0/24 which is over enp0s3.

You mention the "longest prefix match", I usually hear "most specific match", i.e. where the range is the smallest, which indeed implies the longest prefix. However, as stated above, the IP address you're testing does not fall inside the prefix you think it does.

On Debian (and derivatives) there is a very useful utility `netmask`, which can help make things clearer:

```
$ netmask -r 10.0.2.0/255.255.255.192
       10.0.2.0-10.0.2.63       (64)
```

Note that `ip route show` does not show the whole story, it's possible that policy-based routing is in play. You need to also list any routing rules, this is the normal output:

```
$ ip rule show
0:  from all lookup local 
32766:  from all lookup main 
32767:  from all lookup default
```

You can then list the routing entries in a given table this way, here for the "local" table:

```
$ ip route show table local
```

This is called policy based routing. Normally you won't use this (you will if you have more than one internet connection, for example), but it helps to be aware of this when troubleshooting routing problems on systems you didn't configure yourself.